# symfony2 session storage with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, session, symfony, storage

I tried to store my session data into a postgresql database.
I have to precise that with the default session storage i've got any problem.

So i configure my config file as explained here :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html

```
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.pdo

    parameters:
        pdo.db_options:
            db_table:    session
            db_id_col:   session_id
            db_data_col: session_value
            db_time_col: session_time

    pdo:
        class: PDO
        arguments:
            - "pgsql:dbname=%database_name%"
            - %database_user%
            - %database_password%

    session.handler.pdo:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        arguments: [@pdo, %pdo.db_options%]
```

and then when i clear the cache i got this error :

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  authentification peer ?chou?e pour l'utilisateur

here is my script used to create table session :

```
CREATE TABLE session
(
  session_id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  session_value text NOT NULL,
  session_time integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT session_pkey PRIMARY KEY (session_id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE session
  OWNER TO myuser;
```

can't Anyone to help me ?

Comment: Can you check your config.yml according to the symfony doc ? It seems that db_table, db_id_col, etc are related to parameters while they must be related to pdo.db_options (indentation error)

Comment: Please transate error to English.

Comment: many thanks for your response. My config.yml file was ok,  So i fixed here. There is no problem with indentation. the error translated is :CONNECTION FAILURE FOR USER 'myuser'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDO dsn is missing the host :

```
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.pdo

parameters:
    pdo.db_options:
        db_table:    session
        db_id_col:   session_id
        db_data_col: session_value
        db_time_col: session_time

pdo:
    class: PDO
    arguments:
        - "pgsql:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%"
        - %database_user%
        - %database_password%

session.handler.pdo:
    class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    arguments: [@pdo, %pdo.db_options%]
```

Without the host value, i had the same error as you :

```
[PDOException]                                                              
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Many Thanks Picoss. Your response solved my problem however i needed to update my pdo definition service by adding calls method as here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8095